# What version of NPM is compatible with Node.js v13.6.0?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am currently using Node.js v13.6.0 in Windows 8. When I am trying to install the NPM package, it's showing this:

```
npm i npm@6.4.1
npm does not support Node.js v13.6.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! code ERR_REQUIRE_ESM
npm ERR! Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\microshine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\just-diff\index.mjs

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\microshine\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-28T09_17_19_815Z-debug-0.log
```

My system does not support other versions of Node.js so I have to bear with it. Are there any other alternatives to install NPM with this version of Node?

Comment: Note both Node 13 and Windows 8 are out of support. You _should_ probably upgrade to a newer version of Node (and an even-numbered LTS one, at that). But the bundled version of NPM with Node 13.6.0 was 6.13.4, by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happened to me. Then I installed **npm@6.12.1**, & it works for me so **npm install -g npm** should fix this issue.
If the problem still happens then try to upgrade to **Windows 10** with **node v16**. it will surely help you.